# How to access Activitie's binding in Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

This is my toolbar in main_activity.xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            app:title="@{viewModel.title}"
            android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

This is ActivityMainViewModel:

```
class ActivityMainViewModel:ViewModel() {
        
        private val _title = MutableLiveData<String>()
        val title: LiveData<String>
        get() = _title

    init {
        _title.value = "First Value"
    }

    fun setTitle(newTitle: String){
        _title.value = newTitle
    }
}
```

In my Fragment I call the setTitle() method, but the toolbar's title doesn't change in the UI:

```
val activityMainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ActivityMainViewModel::class.java)
activityMainViewModel.setTitle("I want change!")
```

I think that I need a binding instance of MainActivity.
How to get it?

Answer (score 0):

You'd do it like this:

Fragment

```
(activity as YourActivity).supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.your_title)
```

In activity:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
```

Comment: I know. I'm looking for a solution with DataBinding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your fragment your call should be like this:

```
activityMainViewModel.title.postValue("I want change!")
```

In your viewmodel class your method setTitle does not make sense, you could remove it (if you want)

Comment: Your code is like mine. But I encapsulated the title property. Doesn't work.

Comment: have you set your binding variable in your fragment? 

binding.setVariable(BR.viewModel, viewModel)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set content view:

```
ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

And then set the toolbar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(activityMainBinding.toolbar);
```